# Set default values for fields inside multifield in AEM Touch UI

Tags: aem, aem-touch-ui

I want to set default values for fields inside coral ui multifield. I tried to use cq:template but not sure of how to set values for fields inside aem multifieds. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `value` property in fields that you want to have default value.